# Dynamic connection in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I need to do the dunamic connection in cakephp 3.I want to change the database connection as per I pass the database name in configManager::config.
and I want the changed connection in all controller after the connetion changed.

Code of AppBehavior is as follows,

ConnectionManager::drop('myconn1');

$config = ConnectionManager::config('myconn1', [

```
 'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',

 'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',

 'persistent' => false,

 'host' => $databaseDetails['res_host'],

 'username' => $databaseDetails['res_login'],

 'password' => $databaseDetails['res_password'],

 'database' => $databaseDetails['res_database'],

 'encoding' => 'utf8',
 'timezone' => 'UTC',
 'cacheMetadata' => true,
```

]);
ConnectionManager::get('myconn1');

After above code in AppBehavior I have to use the new connection in all controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function ChangeClientConnection($databaseDetails)
{   
    if(isset($databaseDetails) && !empty($databaseDetails))
    {   
        ConnectionManager::drop('conn1');            

        $config = ConnectionManager::config('conn1', [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
            'persistent' => true,
            'host' => $databaseDetails['res_host'],
            'username' => $databaseDetails['res_login'],
            'password' => $databaseDetails['res_password'],
            'database' => $databaseDetails['res_database'],
            'encoding' => 'utf8',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'cacheMetadata' => false,

        ]);            
        $conn = ConnectionManager::get('conn1');
        ConnectionManager::alias('conn1', 'default');
    }
    else
    {
        $conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');

    }   

    return $conn;
}
```